# rails 5 User.find(params[:user_id]) nill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5.1.4 I cant access instant class objects of other Classes at create, new.

e.g `User.find(params[:user_id])` only works in `users_controller`
I have 5 types of users in the same table.
at a point I did this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :assign_default_role

   mount_uploader :avatars, AvatarsUploader
  # :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.jpg", 
  def assign_default_role
    self.add_role(:user) if self.roles.blank?
  end

  belongs_to :lawfirm
  has_many :mycases
  has_many :mycasecomments



      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

now I am not able to access `User.find(params[:attorney_user_id])`a

in say other controllers.

please any help????

Comment: can you show us the specific error that is returned when calling `User.find(params[:attorney_user_id]`

Comment: Is `params[:attorney_user_id]` actually set, what is its value? How do the route definition and the controller method look like? You tagged your question with Rails 4 and 5, what version do you actually use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you find by only using id?

```
User.find(params[:id])
```

Later use SEO friendly url then you will be able to find user by their username.

Comment: I did, it wont work. ok. but I get around it through find_by(params[:attorney_user_id])

Comment: I gotta learn dat in rails